In VBA, how to write an array that references all sheets in my workbook
I am using the code from the spreadsheet guru to mass protect/unprotect my sheets. This file is updated by me and used by other team members. I have some cells open to editing and others not when the sheets are protected.
This sheet gets replaced every year with new sheet names. Rather than listing each sheet name in the array ("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3", etc..) and rewriting this macro every year, is there a way to write it so that the array includes all sheets in the specific file I have open and am attempting to run the macro on? I also want to make sure this does not run on any other files I have open. I am specifically referring to the Inputs SheetArray after all the Dim's.
Sub SheetProtection_Toggle()
'PURPOSE: Add/Remove password protection to a list of tab names
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault**your text**

Dim SheetArray As Variant
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Password As String
Dim NotFoundList As String
Dim WrongPasswordList As String
Dim ProtectionStateDetermined As Boolean
Dim UnprotectSheet As Boolean
Dim x As Long

'INPUTS
  SheetArray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")
  Password = "Password123"

'Loop through each sheet name
  For x = LBound(SheetArray) To UBound(SheetArray)
    'Store Sheet Object to Variable
      On Error Resume Next
      Set sht = Nothing
      Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetArray(x))
      On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Was Sheet found in Activeworkbook?
      If Not sht Is Nothing Then
        'Determine if we need to protect or unprotect these sheets (based off of first instance)
          If ProtectionStateDetermined = False And (sht.ProtectContents Or sht.ProtectDrawingObjects Or sht.ProtectScenarios) Then UnprotectSheet = True
          ProtectionStateDetermined = True
    
        'Lock/Unlock worksheet
          If UnprotectSheet = True Then
            On Error Resume Next
            sht.Unprotect Password
            If sht.ProtectContents = True Then WrongPasswordList = WrongPasswordList & "• " & SheetArray(x) & Chr(10)
            On Error GoTo 0
          Else
            sht.Protect Password
          End If
        
      Else
        'Store a list of sheets not found in the ActiveWorkbook
          NotFoundList = NotFoundList & "• " & SheetArray(x) & Chr(10)
      End If
  Next x

'Report what was done to the worksheets
  If UnprotectSheet = True Then
    MsgBox "Sheets Unprotected!"
  Else
    MsgBox "Sheets Protected!"
  End If

'Report any sheet names that were not found (if applicable)
  If NotFoundList <> "" Then
    MsgBox "The following Worksheets were not found in your Excel file:" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Trim(NotFoundList)
  End If

'Report any sheets that cound not be unprotected (if applicable)
  If WrongPasswordList <> "" Then
    MsgBox "The following Worksheets were unable to be unprotected:" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Trim(WrongPasswordList)
  End If

End Sub


If you want to apply to all sheets, then just loop through the Sheets collection directly.

For Each sht in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets then work with sht inside the loop.


Iterate ThisWorkbook.Worksheets to process each sheet

'Loop through each sheet name
  ' For x = LBound(SheetArray) To UBound(SheetArray)
  For Each sht in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Store Sheet Object to Variable
      ' On Error Resume Next
      ' Set sht = Nothing
      ' Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetArray(x))
      ' On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' 'Was Sheet found in Activeworkbook?
    '   If Not sht Is Nothing Then
        'Determine if we need to protect or unprotect these sheets (based off of first instance)
          If ProtectionStateDetermined = False And (sht.ProtectContents Or sht.ProtectDrawingObjects Or sht.ProtectScenarios) Then UnprotectSheet = True
          ProtectionStateDetermined = True
    
        'Lock/Unlock worksheet
          If UnprotectSheet = True Then
            On Error Resume Next
            sht.Unprotect Password
            If sht.ProtectContents = True Then WrongPasswordList = WrongPasswordList & "• " & SheetArray(x) & Chr(10)
            On Error GoTo 0
          Else
            sht.Protect Password
          End If
        
      ' Else
      '   'Store a list of sheets not found in the ActiveWorkbook
      '     NotFoundList = NotFoundList & "• " & SheetArray(x) & Chr(10)
      ' End If
  Next x

